# wrong position text after img

Tags: html, css, image

there are some confusion in my project

[image]

Why the text isn't at the middle of the header ,here is my html and css :

```
<body>
<header>
    <img height="55px" width="55px;" src="../pic/small-book.png">
    <span class="neworld">Neworld</span>
</header>
</body>

body{
  width: 1200px;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
header{
  width: 1200px;
  height: 55px;
  background-color: white;
  line-height: 55px;
 }
header .neworld{
}
```

I want to know why the neworld is not at the middle and why it isn't unavailable margin-top: -10px; at header .neworld

Answer (score 1):

Give the image and text `float: left` . it will work.

Check this example:   [Demo](http://codepen.io/sifulislam/pen/ZKELjZ)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to vertically align the span text with the image, add this rule:

```
header img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Concerning your second question, why you can't use `margin-top: -10px` on your `.neworld` element: Because margins only have an effect on `block` or  `inline-block` elements. But a `span` is an `inline` element by default.

```css
body {
  width: 1200px;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 55px;
  background-color: white;
  line-height: 55px;
}

header img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <img height="55px" width="55px;" src="../pic/small-book.png">
    <span class="neworld">Neworld</span>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: CSS `vertical-align` is for inline elements. `inline-block` is not needed. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: other question,why margin-left is efficient for inline elements? if the css is header img { margin-left: 100px;} and the image will move to right about 100px

Answer (score 0):

Just apply `vertical-align:middle` to the image:

```css
header img {
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<body>
<header>
    <img height="55" width="55" src="../pic/small-book.png">
    <span class="neworld">Neworld</span>
</header>
</body>
```

Also (FYI), you don't include the `px` or the semi-colon when specifying pixel sizes directly in HTML and it is generally a bad idea to set the `width` and/or `height` of the `body`.

Comment: Thank for your advices, it's helpful for me